# Send data from client to server properly. Server is not receiving full file from client

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu

I am trying to send a JSON file from the client to the server. I have a working program, however, I printed to see what the server receives in the buffer and it doesn't print out the file line by line. I believe it has something to do in the while loop that puts the data in the buffer. I have attached the part of the code with while loop. I also attached my server, client, and JSON file code.
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

```
 //while loop
 while (fgets(buff,MAX,fp) != NULL ) // fgets reads upto MAX character or EOF 
 write(sockfd,buff,sizeof(buff));    // sent the file data to stream
```

```
 //client.c
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <sys/types.h> 
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <json-c/json.h>
 #define MAX 100
 #define SA struct sockaddr 

 void sentFile(int sockfd) 
 { 
     char buff[MAX];                         // for read operation from file and used to sent operation 
     // create file 
     FILE *fp=fopen("myconfig.json","r");    // open file uses both stdio and stdin header files
                                             // file should be present at the program directory

     if( fp == NULL ){
         printf("Error IN Opening File .. \n");
         return ;
     }

     while (fgets(buff,MAX,fp) != NULL ) // fgets reads upto MAX character or EOF 
         write(sockfd,buff,sizeof(buff));    // sent the file data to stream

     fclose (fp);                            // close the file 

     printf("File Sent successfully !!! \n");

 } 

 void parse(int sockfd) {
     char buff[MAX];
     struct json_object *parsed_json; //structure that holds parsed JSON
   //stores rest of fields of the JSON file
   struct json_object *Server_IP_Address;
   struct json_object *Source_Port_Number_UDP;
   struct json_object *Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Head;
   struct json_object *Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Tail;
   struct json_object *Port_Number_TCP;
   struct json_object *Size_UDP_Payload;
   struct json_object *Inter_Measurement_Time;
   struct json_object *Number_UDP_Packets;
   struct json_object *TTL_UDP_Packets;

   FILE *fp=fopen("myconfig.json","r");
   fread(buff, 1024, 1, fp); //reads files and puts contents inside buffer
   parsed_json = json_tokener_parse(buff); //parse json file's contents and convert them into a json object

   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Server_IP_Address", &Server_IP_Address);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Source_Port_Number_UDP", &Source_Port_Number_UDP);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Head", &Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Head);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Tail", &Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Tail);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Port_Number_TCP", &Port_Number_TCP);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Size_UDP_Payload", &Size_UDP_Payload);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Inter_Measurement_Time", &Inter_Measurement_Time);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Number_UDP_Packets", &Number_UDP_Packets);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "TTL_UDP_Packets", &TTL_UDP_Packets);

   printf("Server_IP_Address: %s\n", json_object_get_string(Server_IP_Address));
   printf("Source_Port_Number_UDP: %s\n", json_object_get_string(Source_Port_Number_UDP));
   printf("Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Head: %s\n", json_object_get_string(Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Head));
   printf("Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Tail: %s\n", json_object_get_string(Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Tail));
   printf("Port_Number_TCP: %s\n", json_object_get_string(Port_Number_TCP));
   printf("Size_UDP_Payload: %s\n", json_object_get_string(Size_UDP_Payload));
   printf("Inter_Measurement_Time: %s\n", json_object_get_string(Inter_Measurement_Time));
   printf("Number_UDP_Packets: %d\n", json_object_get_int(Number_UDP_Packets));
   printf("TTL_UDP_Packets: %d\n", json_object_get_int(TTL_UDP_Packets));

 }

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
 { 
     int sockfd, connfd; 
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli; 

     // socket create and varification 
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
     if (sockfd == -1) { 
         printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
         exit(0); 
     } 
     else
         printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 

     bzero(&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

     // assign IP, PORT 
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.249");
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8765);

     // connect the client socket to server socket 
     if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) != 0) { 
         printf("connection with the server failed...\n"); 
         exit(0); 
     } 
     else
         printf("connected to the server..\n"); 
     FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

     // function for sending File 
     sentFile(sockfd); 
     parse(sockfd);

     // close the socket 
     close(sockfd); 
 }
```

```
 //server.c
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <sys/types.h> 
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <json-c/json.h>
 #define MAX 100
 #define SA struct sockaddr 

 void recvFile(int sockfd) 
 { 
     char buff[MAX];     // to store message from client

     FILE *fp=fopen("myconfig.json","w");

     if( fp == NULL ){
         printf("Error IN Opening File ");
         return ;
     }

     while( read(sockfd,buff,MAX) > 0 )
         fprintf(fp,"%s",buff);

 } 

 void parse(int sockfd) {
     char buff[MAX];
     struct json_object *parsed_json; //structure that holds parsed JSON
   //stores rest of fields of the JSON file
   struct json_object *Server_IP_Address;
   struct json_object *Source_Port_Number_UDP;
   struct json_object *Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Head;
   struct json_object *Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Tail;
   struct json_object *Port_Number_TCP;
   struct json_object *Size_UDP_Payload;
   struct json_object *Inter_Measurement_Time;
   struct json_object *Number_UDP_Packets;
   struct json_object *TTL_UDP_Packets;

   FILE *fp=fopen("myconfig.json","r");
   fread(buff, 1024, 1, fp); //reads files and puts contents inside buffer
   parsed_json = json_tokener_parse(buff); //parse json file's contents and convert them into a json object

   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Server_IP_Address", &Server_IP_Address);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Source_Port_Number_UDP", &Source_Port_Number_UDP);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Head", &Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Head);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Tail", &Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Tail);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Port_Number_TCP", &Port_Number_TCP);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Size_UDP_Payload", &Size_UDP_Payload);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Inter_Measurement_Time", &Inter_Measurement_Time);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "Number_UDP_Packets", &Number_UDP_Packets);
   json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "TTL_UDP_Packets", &TTL_UDP_Packets);

   printf("Server_IP_Address: %s\n", json_object_get_string(Server_IP_Address));
   printf("Source_Port_Number_UDP: %s\n", json_object_get_string(Source_Port_Number_UDP));
   printf("Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Head: %s\n", json_object_get_string(Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Head));
   printf("Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Tail: %s\n", json_object_get_string(Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Tail));
   printf("Port_Number_TCP: %s\n", json_object_get_string(Port_Number_TCP));
   printf("Size_UDP_Payload: %s\n", json_object_get_string(Size_UDP_Payload));
   printf("Inter_Measurement_Time: %s\n", json_object_get_string(Inter_Measurement_Time));
   printf("Number_UDP_Packets: %d\n", json_object_get_int(Number_UDP_Packets));
   printf("TTL_UDP_Packets: %d\n", json_object_get_int(TTL_UDP_Packets));

 }

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
 { 
     int sockfd, connfd, len;                // create socket file descriptor 
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli;      // create structure object of sockaddr_in for client and server

     // socket create and verification 
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);           // creating a TCP socket ( SOCK_STREAM )

     if (sockfd == -1) { 
         printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
         exit(0); 
     } 
     else
         printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 

     // empty the 
     bzero(&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

     // assign IP, PORT 
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.218");
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8765);

     // Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification 
     if ((bind(sockfd, (SA*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))) != 0) { 
         printf("socket bind failed...\n"); 
         exit(0); 
     } 
     else
         printf("Socket successfully binded..\n"); 

     // Now server is ready to listen and verification 
     if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0) { 
         printf("Listen failed...\n"); 
         exit(0); 
     } 
     else
         printf("Server listening..\n"); 
     FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");

     len = sizeof(cli); 

     // Accept the data packet from client and verification 
     connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&cli, &len);   // accepts connection from socket

     if (connfd < 0) { 
         printf("server acccept failed...\n"); 
         exit(0); 
     } 
     else
         printf("server acccept the client...\n"); 

     // Function for chatting between client and server 
     recvFile(connfd);
     parse(sockfd);

     // After transfer close the socket 
     close(sockfd); 
 }
```

```
{

 //myconfig.json
 "Server_IP_Address": "127.0.0.1",
     "Source_Port_Number_UDP": "9876",
     "Destination_Port_Number_UDP": "8765",
     "Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Head": "x",
     "Destination_Port_Number_TCP_Tail": "y",
     "Port_Number_TCP": "22",
     "Size_UDP_Payload": "1000",
     "Inter_Measurement_Time": "15",
     "Number_UDP_Packets": "6000",
     "TTL_UDP_Packets": "255",

}
```

Comment: Not reading line by line doesn't seem to be the problem here. Just write the data received into myconfig.json, it doesn't matter if it's written 'line by line' or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the write():

```
write(sockfd,buff,sizeof(buff));
```

should be

```
write(sockfd,buff,strlen(buff) + 1);
```

See here: [how to pass the entire string over the read and write function in TCP socket programming in c program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187216/how-to-pass-the-entire-string-over-the-read-and-write-function-in-tcp-socket-pro)

Comment: I tried this and it did not work as well. The file that the server receives is broken and I when I ask the server to print what it receives. It prints a bunch of broken up values.

Comment: Try to printf() a line to screen after receiving it, and see what you get. (Without using parse() or write to file)